Help with Star Battle puzzle

I made it through all the easy levels without ever having to consciously divide the whole grid into specific regions. I've seen that this is a common technique, but it confuses me even more when trying to apply.
Now I'm trying the hard levels but I am stuck. Please solve this step by step.

Welcome to Puzzling.SE! While this is a good question overall, I would like to know one thing - where did you get this from? Our code of conduct states that you have to give proper attribution if you did not make the puzzle yourself. Other than that, I hope you enjoy your stay here!

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

This appears to be from the Star Battle Go app created by Summit Studio.

Take a look at the:

 Fifth row from the top.

It requires:

 Two stars.  One is in the first two cells.  The other has to be in the larger shape in the middle.  That shape already has one star in it in row 6 and allows you to mark the rest of that shape off.

Image:

 

Further Steps and Tricks:
Any 2x2 set of cells can only have one star.
Look at:

 Column 2 and 3, and 4 and 5 together.

 The orange cells must have a star in each 2x2.  The purple cells must have a star in each 2x2.  This means the brown cells cannot have a star.

Most of these techniques are covered here (KrazyDad is the source of this puzzle)
https://krazydad.com/twonottouch/
https://krazydad.com/twonottouch/intro_tutorial/
https://krazydad.com/twonottouch/med_tutorial/
https://krazydad.com/twonottouch/adv_tutorial/
